# Paramiko process ends early

Tags: python, paramiko

I am trying to run a command on multiple computers but the command starts and then ends almost immediately. It takes a while to run so I just want to start  and then move onto the next computer.

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
un = 'username'
pw = 'password'
version = None
count = 0

for i in xrange(1):
    host = 'hydra' + str(i) + '.eecs.utk.edu'

    try:
        conn = client.connect(host, username=un, password=pw)
    except:
        continue
    count += 1
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls ./neuro/networks/anets/')

    #gets highest numbered folder to compute next version
    if version == None:
        version = max(map(int, stdout.read().split())) + 1

    anew = 'mkdir ~/neuro/networks/anets/{}'.format(version)
    bnew = 'mkdir ~/neuro/networks/bnets/{}'.format(version)

    #this is the command that ends too early
    net = 'nice -n 19 ~/neuro/apps/polebalance/bin/PBEO > ~/neuro/networks/anets/{v}/net{pc:02d}_{v}.txt'.format(v=version, pc=i)
    print '.../anets/{v}/net{pc:02d}_{v}.txt'.format(v=version, pc=i)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(anew)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(bnew)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(net)

    client.close()
print 'making {} nets'.format(count)
```

Does anyone know how to start a process and then terminate the session without the process terminating?

Comment: The command ends immediately, or it takes a while to run?

Comment: Are you envisioning something that threads would not solve?

Comment: @StephenRauch The command should take a while to run but it gets cut off early

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command with `nohup` to disable the hang-up signal and end it with `&` to run in the background. Now your ssh can exit and it will keep going. You should wait for `exec_command` to complete when making the directories, just in case the system is slow for a moment. I combined both makes into one so there is only one wait. Other than that, I only added `nohup` and `&` to the net command.

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
un = 'username'
pw = 'password'
version = None
count = 0

for i in xrange(1):
    host = 'hydra' + str(i) + '.eecs.utk.edu'

    try:
        conn = client.connect(host, username=un, password=pw)
    except:
        continue
    count += 1
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls ./neuro/networks/anets/')

    #gets highest numbered folder to compute next version
    if version == None:
        version = max(map(int, stdout.read().split())) + 1

    anew = 'mkdir ~/neuro/networks/anets/{}'.format(version)
    bnew = 'mkdir ~/neuro/networks/bnets/{}'.format(version)

    #this is the command that ends too early
    net = 'nohup nice -n 19 ~/neuro/apps/polebalance/bin/PBEO > ~/neuro/networks/anets/{v}/net{pc:02d}_{v}.txt &'.format(v=version, pc=i)
    print '.../anets/{v}/net{pc:02d}_{v}.txt'.format(v=version, pc=i)

    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(';'.join((anew, bnew)))
    # wait directory creation done
    stdout.read()
    # cmd in background with nohup so won't exit on ssh exit
    client.exec_command(net)
    client.close()

print 'making {} nets'.format(count)
```

**UPDATE**

This test program runs itself on the local computer via ssh. Each remote command write to a log file that we read to make sure it worked.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import os
import paramiko
import getpass
import time

def remote_command(logfile):
    print("remote command", logfile)
    with open(logfile, 'w') as fp:
        pid = os.getpid()
        fp.write('{}: Proof of life, pid {}\n'.format(
            time.ctime(), pid))
        fp.flush()
        for i in range(20):
            print('remote', pid)
            time.sleep(.5)
        fp.write("{}: done\n".format(time.ctime()))

def runner():
    print("Run remote execution test via ssh on local computer")
    username = getpass.getuser()
    password = getpass.getpass()
    my_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    my_prog = os.path.abspath(__file__)
    if my_prog[-1] == 'c':
        del my_prog[-1]
    life_files = []
    for i in range(3):
        # remote writes this, but since its really our machine
        # we can read it later.
        life_files.append(os.path.join(my_dir, '{}-{}.text'.format(
            os.getpid(), i)))
        client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        client.connect('localhost', username=username, password=password)
        cmd = 'nohup {} {} {} &'.format(sys.executable, my_prog, 
            life_files[-1])
        print('running', cmd)
        client.exec_command(cmd)
        client.close()

    print("verify all started")
    time.sleep(2) # allow time for python to start...
    for name in life_files:
        print(open(name).readline(), end='')

    print("verify all ended")
    for i in range(10, 0, -1):
        sys.stdout.write('{}..'.format(i))
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
    print()
    for name in life_files:
        print(open(name).read(), end='')

if __name__=="__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        runner()
    elif len(sys.argv) == 2:
        remote_command(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print("bad command line")
        exit(1)
```

On my machine the result is

```
$ python3 test.py
Run remote execution test via ssh on local computer
Password: 
running nohup /usr/bin/python3 /home/td/tmp/test.py /home/td/tmp/27212-0.text &
running nohup /usr/bin/python3 /home/td/tmp/test.py /home/td/tmp/27212-1.text &
running nohup /usr/bin/python3 /home/td/tmp/test.py /home/td/tmp/27212-2.text &
verify all started
Sun Apr  9 13:05:30 2017: Proof of life, pid 27232
Sun Apr  9 13:05:31 2017: Proof of life, pid 27255
Sun Apr  9 13:05:31 2017: Proof of life, pid 27275
verify all ended
10..9..8..7..6..5..4..3..2..1..
Sun Apr  9 13:05:30 2017: Proof of life, pid 27232
Sun Apr  9 13:05:40 2017: done
Sun Apr  9 13:05:31 2017: Proof of life, pid 27255
Sun Apr  9 13:05:41 2017: done
Sun Apr  9 13:05:31 2017: Proof of life, pid 27275
Sun Apr  9 13:05:41 2017: done
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem.  I've noticed that if I run the command manually it prints a PID but not when I execute it through the script.

Comment: _I just want to start and then move onto the next computer_ - `nohup` detaches stdout/err and then the command runs in the background. If you want to "move on", you won't see the program's output. If you want to grab the output, then a different technique is to run them all in threads.

Comment: regardless of whether I use nohup or not I get the same output and result.  I've also tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105029/process-dies-if-it-is-run-via-paramiko-ssh-session-and-with-in-the-end) solution and it didn't work either.

Comment: You won't see output if you close the connection. It worked in my tests. I'll post a working example.

Comment: I added a working example so we have a common ground to compare.