# How can I do a nohup command using airflows ssh_operator?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm new to airflow and I'm trying to run a job on an ec2 instance using airflow's ssh_operator like shown below:

```
t2 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_conn_id='ec2_ssh_connection',
    task_id='execute_script',
    command="nohup python test.py &",
    retries=3,
    dag=dag)
```

The job takes few hours and I want airflow to execute the python script and end. However when the command is executed and the dag completes the script is terminated on the ec2 instance. I also noticed that the above code doesn't create a nohup.out file.

I'm looking at how to run nohup using SSHOperator. It seems like this might be a python related issue because I'm getting the following error on EC2 script when the nohup has been executed:

```
[Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does SSHOperator writes to the log?

Comment: I thought it would write to nohup.out but then I added following command to capture logs: nohup python test.py > test.log &

Comment: I mean the [operator log in the AIRFLOW_HOME](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/howto/write-logs.html#writing-logs-locally). You can also access it in [the UI](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/ui.html#task-instance-context-menu): click the operator, then view log).

Comment: I don't get any error it just processes it but the python script that is using multiprocessing on ec2 errors out with [Errno 32] Broken pipe seems like when the SSHOperator closes connection it causes that error. I thought nohup will solve that issue. If I ran the same script manually from ec2 it doesn't error out.

Comment: I believe it's either `nohup` or `&`, not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Airflow's `SSHHook` uses the Paramiko module for SSH connectivity. There is [an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105029/process-dies-if-it-is-run-via-paramiko-ssh-session-and-with-in-the-end) regarding Prarmiko and `nohup`. One of the answers suggests to add `sleep` after the `nohup` command. I cannot explain exactly why, but it actually works. It is also necessary  to set `get_pty=True` in `SSHOperator`.

Here is a complete example that demonstrates the solution:

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator


default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2001, 2, 3, 4, 0),
}

with DAG(
    'a_dag', schedule_interval=None, default_args=default_args, catchup=False,
) as dag:
    op = SSHOperator(
        task_id='ssh',
        ssh_conn_id='ssh_default',
        command=(
            'nohup python -c "import time;time.sleep(30);print(1)" & sleep 10'
        ),
        get_pty=True,  # This is needed!
    )
```

The `nohup.out` file is written to the user's `$HOME`.

Comment: Thanks, trying it out. The scripts on ec2 uses LokyBackend. So far adding time and get_pty=True allows all LokyBackend backend to complete that were executed during the time delay but once the timer is over the remaining lines in the python script errors out. Maybe I did something wrong. Revising it.

Comment: @codeBarer I see you accepted the answer. Were you able to resolve the LokyBackend issue? What was the problem?

Comment: Hi I did. adding that time delay and sleep did it for LockyBackend. But it only works for the modules/functions that were executed within that interval, so after time out they keep running. As for the modules that follows with other threads didn't execute. So I'm thinking of creating a daemon on the EC2 and using airflow to update env vars to avoid any issues.

Comment: `get_pty=True` turns the SSH connection into a non-blocking connection. Otherwise SSHOperator will block and wait for responses from the started processes - including decoupled processes, i. e. wait forever or until the connection breaks.